# Installation Error on Netbook with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, ubuntu-netbook

I'm trying to install 12.04 on an ASUS eee pc 1005pe with a USB stick. The installation starts normally, then it says it has encountered an error and takes me to a desktop where nothing works. I shut it down the hard way and tried again, same result. Now it just goes to a cursor blinking on a black background. What went wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Hard to tell from your description. Did you check the md5sum of the iso ?

Comment: See [HowToMD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) on how to do what @bodhi.zazen suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're dead set on using Ubuntu, I would try installing Xubuntu or Even Lubuntu. I have an older eeepc (2G Surf) and this worked for me.

Also try installing Ubuntu from an external CD drive.